# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined cordova-plugin-contact

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

i have a problem when run code on my app. I'm using cordova-plugin-contacts, but does not work

```
 getContato(){
      this.contacts.pickContact()
      .then((data)=>{
        console.log(data)
      })
    }
```

Error:

```
ConvidadoPage.html:25 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
at get (vendor.js:70203)
at getPlugin (vendor.js:70235)
at checkAvailability (vendor.js:103018)
at vendor.js:208058
at Contacts.pickContact (vendor.js:208063)
at ConvidadoPage.webpackJsonp.389.ConvidadoPage.getContato (main.js:1182)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ConvidadoPage.html:25)
at handleEvent (vendor.js:13963)
at callWithDebugContext (vendor.js:15472)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (vendor.js:15059)
```

Comment: Is it possible to run `console.log(this.contacts)` and see what it shows? Inside `getContato()` function in very first line.

Comment: Yes. It is possible.
 `Contacts {} proto: IonicNativePlugin constructor: ƒ Contacts() platforms: (9) ["Android", "BlackBerry 10", "Browser", "Firefox OS", "iOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows", "Windows 8", "Windows Phone"] plugin: "cordova-plugin-contacts" pluginName: "Contacts" pluginRef: "navigator.contacts" repo: "github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts" `

Comment: But, i whant get pick selected contacts

Comment: I need more details, something like a jsfiddle that will reproduce the same error.

Comment: I finding problem solution. I uninstallong lastest plugin and install version   3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finding problem solution. I uninstallong lastest plugin and install version   3.0.0

Comment: Nice. Thanks for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. I fixed it with Following steps:

Remove Ionic native plugin Contacts and then

Install Ionic native plugin Contacts at version 4.20 
use this command to install->

1. npm install @ionic-native/contacts@4.20.0